# Typo in the past date sentence

Tags: bug, grammatical-correction

If you will see  right sidebar on the attached image, where it says Upcoming events and : Election ends 10 hours ago.
This is where I want to correct, as the election is already over and "ends" is wrong here.

I am not certain if this is the right place to report this or if this is really a grammatical mistake which won't come in future.

[image]

Comment: Do you still see the announcement? It's not shown for me.

Comment: The announcement is no more shown.